# SQL Query for joining multiple tables containing multiple rows - The right way?

Tags: php, mysql, join, query-optimization

I have a situation where I have 4 tables of following schema :

```
#1 : Table USER
user_id | user_details....

#2 : Table POSTS
post_id | user_id | post_details....

#3 : Table REPLIES
reply_id | post_id | by_user_id | reply_details...

#4 : Tables REPLY_PHOTOS
photo_id | reply_id | photo_details...
```

I want to retrieve all the posts of a particular user along with the replies on them and the photos in the replies. Every usage of columns from the previous table is in foreign key constraint.

```
SELECT USER.user_id, POST.post_id, REPLIES.reply_id, REPLY_PHOTOS.photo_id
FROM USER WHERE USER.user_id = 1
LEFT JOIN POST on USER.user_id = POST.user_id
LEFT JOIN REPLIES on POST.post_id = REPLIES.post_id
LEFT JOIN REPLY_PHOTOS on REPLIES.reply_id = REPLY_PHOTOS.reply_id;
```

The problem I'm facing is, when I am using joins normally I am getting rows that I suspect is not good practice.

Example of result I'm getting for `user_id = 1` :

```
user_id | post_id | reply_id | photo_id
--------Post 1 - Reply 1 (Repeat for photos)----------------
   1         23        17         26
   1         23        17         32
   1         23        17         47
-------Post 1 - Reply 2 (Repeat for its photos)-----------
   1         23        34         12
   1         23        34         18
   1         23        34         23
   1         23        34         31
------Post 1 - Reply 3 (Contains no photos)------------
   1         23        41         null
---------Next Post for same user (contd.)----------------
```

As a user can have multiple posts, so multiple post_id's are related to a single user id.
A post can contain multiple replies, so multiple reply_id's are related to a single post.
A reply can contain multiple photos, so multiple photo_id's are related to a single reply.

Also, I want to further extend it to store Likes which will be another pain in the ass.

I don't know if my schema needs to be change (if yes, suggest me a better way) or if I'm not able to understand the basics of join.

If this is the way results should be, then how can I traverse to all the fields in `php` without much issues?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "traverse all the fields"? The database scheme looks fine to me.

Comment: Yes, instead of `user_id` traverse everything related to that particular `user_id`. But the problem is the repeating results (if that is a problem). Also I'm using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`, because I want the left column no matter what.

Comment: Well, depending on what you're trying to achieve, there are different approaches possible. What do you want to do in that particular situation?

Comment: What can be different possible approaches, I want to know that. Also, in this situation I want to get all the post a user has posted with the replies associated to that post and the photos associated with the replies. If there is any better way to do that, please suggest me. Also, how would bigger websites handle such kind of situations?

Comment: Well, you could get the data in a more structured way by first getting the ids of all posts, then get all the replies for each post and so on. However, that of course needs more database queries. The other alternative would be writing a custom "parser" function that parses such query results into a custom data structure that you then use for displaying what you need.

Comment: I don't want to use multiple queries when I can use JOINS. Also, I don't want to use functions ans procedures as it would be hard to track and change for me later. If I'm supposed to get results like I've shown above using JOINS, then I'll consider going that way. I just wanted to know if what I'm doing can be improved performance wise (by any means)?

Comment: Performance-wise on database level? JOINs are pretty quick when done using conditions on fields that have indexes on them.

Comment: I have indexes on every `id` fields that i'm using here cuz i knew that i would mostly select the results based on their `ids`. But only thing I am asking is "Is this query good? Or can i achieve this without having repeating values?". I thought of using `group concat` but that could only be used on the last table from which I'm selecting data because `id` from one table is used to fetch data from other. So, `concat` does not make sense if I am having more than 3 tables (because repeating values would still be there.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time I would quite happily process the duplicate parts of the returned rows, ignoring them. However in this situation you could get away with using GROUP_CONCAT.

Something like this:-

```
SELECT USER.user_id, POST.post_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('~',REPLIES.reply_id, REPLY_PHOTOS.photo_id)) AS ReplyPhotoId
FROM USER WHERE USER.user_id = 1
LEFT JOIN POST on USER.user_id = POST.user_id
LEFT JOIN REPLIES on POST.post_id = REPLIES.post_id
LEFT JOIN REPLY_PHOTOS on REPLIES.reply_id = REPLY_PHOTOS.reply_id
GROUP BY USER.user_id, POST.post_id
```

Then you can explode out the ReplyPhotoId field (on the commas by default), and for each element of that resulting array explode it again based on ~.

Comment: I was thinking `GROUP_CONCAT` but was confused that if we can concat multiple columns as you did right there. Thanks for the reply btw. Can you show a fiddle, please?

Comment: Forget the fiddle. I got it right using your method. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: Glad I don't have to do the fiddle. Typing this on a laptop while watching TV, and it is a pain to do any serious editing!